# WSO2 ESB Amazon EC2 BAM Connectivity

Tags: amazon-ec2, wso2, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

I have WSO2 ESB and WSO2 BAM running as Amazon EC2 instance, I am trying to configure BAM Server Profile from ESB management console.
What should I put under IP Address  -  Do I need to put public DNS name of WSO2 BAM EC2 instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not worked with an Amazon EC2 instance. But if you can put the IP address or the host name it should work. Do not care if the test button fails.

Comment: Amazon EC2 has dynamic IP and dynamic public DNS name, therefore during each restart of these instances generate new IP address or DNS name. How to ensure BAM server profile works without changing server configurations under such case.

Comment: I am able to publish event though Test button says unable to connect to BAM server !!!

Comment: Is there any Amazon EC2 AMI available for WSO2 ESB or BAM or CEP ?

Comment: No. We do not have them.

Answer (score 0):

EC2 has dynamic IPs which are generated each time your instance starts. To get round this, AWS has Elastic IPs.

Elastic IPs are allocated and can be attached or detached to your instance at any point (you will need to reattach them after the instance restarts).

An alternative would be to launch into a VPC, which will give you your own private IP range and you can configure as you want. You can even assign multiple private IPs to a single host.

[The most simple VPC layout just has a public subnet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario1.html) but, for better security, [you can use a public and private subnet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html). If this is all new to you, it may be best to stick with the most simple scenario, and create your resources using wizards.